# Using coldfusion to find my music

Tags: coldfusion, dos

Non work related so this isn't urgent:

I found a post by Ray Camden [here](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2006/2/6/Ask-a-Jedi-Dumping-a-Recursive-Directory-List) that will recurse a specific folder path.  I want to extend this to search my computer for my music files.  I know I have duplicates and if I can find the files, i can remove them.

Ultimately, i want to build a music library/catalog so that I will stop buy the same music twice (or three times in some cases - I'm embarassed to admit that but it is what it is).  I've thought about writing an ms-dos script to search and output the results to a file, and then loop over the file to store the contents into a database.  This does seem to be a faster process than what CF can do, not to mention the script wont run into the 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' issue.

If you know of something like that that already exists, can you post a link or give me your two cents on which way would be better?  I have several drives that I've acquired over the years of new computers and there is crap on just about all of them since some of them are now my backup drives.

Comment: If I go the MS-DOS route, I only know of DIR or TREE commands.  Would there be a better method for searching the hard drive (via ms-dos) than one of these methods?

Comment: Unless this is for fun, why re-invent the wheel? [Find & Remove Duplicate Songs, Mp3, iTunes, iPod and Music Files.](http://www.ashisoft.com/duplicate-songs-finder.htm)

Comment: @JamesHill - it is for fun but once I get this tweaked for music, I also want to do this for my movies, videos, etc.  Then what I'll do is create a web page off of my site so that the next time I'm at Best Buy, Block Buster, whatever, I can search my database and make sure I don't already have the movie, video, song, etc.  But again, yeah this is for fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making ms-dos batch file to scour the drives using the following switches, `dir /s /b *.mp3 *.wma *.m4a *.flac *.mp4 *.m4a *.m4v *.mp3PRO *.mp2 *.wav > music_files.txt`  and then just performing a loop over the file and inserting the records into my sql database.  I can do this again with my videos - I found my wedding video 6 times (LOL).  I did not want to be like Ray Barone and record the super bowl over the video I guess.  :)

Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfdirectory action="list" recurse="yes" directory="c:/" query="MyFiles>

<cfloop query="MyFiles">
    <cfif RIGHT(MyFiles.name,4) EQ ".mp3">
         <!--- DUMP DATA TO DATABASE---->
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Then use sql queries to find duplicate files.

Comment: On smaller drives, this might work.  What I'm finding is there is too much "garbage" being returned based on the amount or processing that is required to recurse all of the directories.  In other words, I'm getting a java heap error message - even after increasing the java heap memory.

Comment: You could run cfdirectory without recursing, then loop deeper and deeper with separate queries.  Maybe build in some exclude conditions to ignore folders you know you wouldn't store files in (ie: C:/Windows).